# Защита ELF от LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c++, linux, elf

Имеется исполняемый ELF файл «glinkd». Мне необходимо дополнить реализацию некоторых функций, посредством их перехвата. Попался под руку удобный инструмент `LD_PRELOAD`. Он прекрасно отрабатывает на любых elf файлах, но к несчастью, необходимый для меня файл патчить он отказался. Это выражается в том, что при подгрузки моей библиотеки в «glinkd», попросту ничего не происходит, как будто на этом файле имеется какая то защита.

В гугле ничего про защиту от `LD_PRELOAD` я не нашел.

Как я патчу elf файлы:

1. **testso.cpp**:

   ```
   #include <cstdio>

   void __attribute__ ((constructor)) module_load(void);
   void __attribute__ ((destructor)) module_unload(void);

   void module_load(void)
   {
       printf("hello from .so!\n");
   }

   void module_unload(void)
   {
   }
   ```

   Компилирую:

   g++ -fPIC -c testso.cpp -o testso.o -m32 -std=c++0x
     g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libtestso.so -o libtestso.so testso.o -m32 -std=c++0x
2. **test_prog.cpp:**

   ```
   #include <cstdio>

   int main()
   {
       printf("Hello from executable!\n");
   }
   ```

   Компилирую:

   g++ -o test_prog test_prog.cpp -m32
3. Патчим **test_prog**:

   ```
   root@ubuntu:/home/glinkd# LD_PRELOAD=/home/glinkd/libtestso.so ./test_prog
   hello from .so!
   Hello from executable!
   root@ubuntu:/home/glinkd#
   ```
4. Патчим **glinkd**:

   ```
   root@ubuntu:/home/glinkd# LD_PRELOAD=/home/glinkd/libtestso.so ./glinkd
   Usage: ./glinkd configurefile section_num
   root@ubuntu:/home/glinkd#
   ```

Как видим, наша `.so` просто игнорируется. Есть идеи что это за защита, и как ее можно снять?

Comment: А это не защита. Просто он слинкован статически и не использует динамическую загрузку библиотек

Comment: есть какой нибудь способ заставить glinkd пропатчиться через LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: даже если удастся загрузить их как то совместно, стандартный механизм подмены функций не заработает. потому как в таком файле все требуемые функции уже включены в него и он извне цеплять ничего не будет.

Comment: мне как раз и нужно перехватить включенные функции, которые содержатся в .text секции.

Comment: А как вы это хотели делать с помощью LD_PRELOAD. он же стандарным образом подменит только загружаемые извне. не сколько я могу понять. А если вы хотите сами поправить вызовы в оперативной памяти, то пусть ваш процесс загрузит этот с помощью clone в разделяемую память и правит сколько ему хочется (скорее всего придется снимать защиту сегмента кода от записи)

Comment: все что мне нужно от LD_PRELOAD, это подгрузить мою .so библиотеку в процесс, и вызвать module_load() (конструктор .so), который в свою очередь пропишет в начало перехватываемой функции прыжок на мой перехватчик.

Comment: Это невозможно. что бы LD_PRELOAD сработал надо что бы его кто то  задействовал, а его задействует динамический загрузчик, который работает только с динамически собранными выполнимыми файлами. Работа со статически слинковаными возможно только самостоятельной загрузкой требуемого ELF в свое адресное пространство.

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение. Каким образом можно загрузить произвольный ELF в свое адресное пространство?

Comment: Если бы я это знал - ответ бы написал ... Вот, нарыл тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690454/how-to-compile-and-execute-from-memory-directly  Там еще много ссылок, есть что поизучать ...

Comment: Решил попробовать вызывать свою .so из glinkd методом вызова dlopen в main(). Выводит след. ошибку:
**glinkd: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot handle TLS data**
<br> Есть идеи, в чем проблема?

Comment: @TheCooler скорее всего  конфликт libstdc++ собранной статически и динимечски при попытке работать в рамках одного адрессного пространства.

Answer (score 2):

*Из комментария пользователя [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike):*

Это невозможно. Чтобы `LD_PRELOAD` сработал, надо, чтобы его кто то задействовал, а его задействует динамический загрузчик. Но он работает только с динамически собранными исполняемыми файлами. Работа при статической компоновке возможна только самостоятельной загрузкой требуемого ELF в свое адресное пространство.